# Should I say that I add Video "before"or"in front of" game?

Tags: grammar

Should I say that I type Video "before"or"in front of" game?

For example

> You should add "Video" BEFORE " games". You missed typing it.

Or

> Me: I like games
>
> Teacher:You missed "video" IN FRONT OF "games". You missed the word.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you explain a bit more about what you want to know?

Comment: I edit it. Hope it better

Comment: Are you asking whether it is more correct to say "add 'video' *before* 'games'" or to say "add 'video' *in front of* 'games'"?

Comment: @DJClayworth  Yes.  I want to know how to use the words when I apply it on lecture and in real life correction to presentation.

Comment: By the way, you might also be interested in our [ell.se] site.

Comment: I've edited your question. Please check it means what you wanted it to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For practical purposes there is no difference between "before" and "in front of" in the sentences you talk about. Either is correct.

If you were a technical pedantic grammatician you might say that "before" refers to time, and "in front of" refers to position, but in normal usage, even in formal writing, "before" is going to be acceptable and understood.

The only time you might want to avoid it is if there is a danger of confusing time order with word order, in which case you might want to use "in front of" to avoid the confusion.

> I typed the word "games" before the other words, and after that I typed "video" in front of it.

Comment: I would argue with a 'pedantic grammarian' who told me that I could not say or write 'I stood before the Mona Lisa and gazed at it'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I would be on your side in that argument.

Comment: @DJClayworth Please ,if you also talk about the "after", it would be more nearly perfect for my learning :)  Please, this is a request from me :) Please write it :)